# How to store a single value in a RDD or do you absolutely need to convert it to an Array?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a running program which does a bunch of transformations on an input RDD which contains an array of Integers. But after all the transformations are done, I want to just find the sum of all those numbers and get only 1 integer and store that value in an output file.

I am able to get the final integer value by performing the `reduce` operation on the RDD. But then, after this ACTION is performed, I get an integer returned to me (and not a RDD) so I cannot use the `RDD.saveAsTextFile("/output_location")` method.

Also, it gives me an error when I try to create an RDD for that integer:

```
// finalvalue is my variable that contains the output value to be stored.
val out = sc.parallelize(finalvalue);
```

The error: `Type Mismatch, expected Seq[NotInferedT], actual: Int`

Can someone explain to me why can't I store one single value into a RDD or do I have to convert it into an Array?

Comment: There is no reason nor logic behind converting a single value to an RDD. You shouldn't forget that working with a distributed computing framework doesn't allow you to use basic programming knowledge, thus I suggest that the correct answer is @DanielDarabos for best practice for one value or even a small set of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let us consider the scenario and understand one step at a time:

```
// Creating the RDD named x which stores 3 integers
scala> val x = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3))
x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:12

// Now calculating the sum converting it into an Integer and storing in mysum variable
scala> val mysum = x.sum().toInt
[Stage 1:>                                                                                                                       (0 + 0) / 2]mysum: Int = 6
```

So far so good. Now when you try to create the RDD just using the sc.parallelize() on the mysum, following happens:

```
scala> val sumRDD = sc.parallelize(mysum)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Seq[?]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val sumRDD = sc.parallelize(mysum)
                                   ^
```

As the error suggests, you can only provide a Sequence as an argument to the parallelize method. So solve this you either need to pass an Array (or Seq, etc.) or a string to the parallelize:

```
// So either do this
scala> val sumRDD = sc.parallelize(mysum.toString)
sumRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Char] = ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:16

// or do this
scala> val sumRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(mysum))
sumRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[6] at parallelize at <console>:16
```

Next step is to store it to a particular path. 'file' is to store it on the local machine and 'hdfs' to store on HDFS, respectively

```
scala> sumRDD.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/hdfs/a12")
15/08/19 16:14:57 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
```

- Not sure why the Warning came in the last step when I tried to store string on the Disk.

And a directory is created at the above mentioned path with part files in it.

Comment: `sc.parallelize(mysum.toString)` — Great idea! Each digit of the number will be on a separate line and these lines will be distributed across multiple files. An exciting puzzle for anyone who wants to use the result.

Comment: @Jordan; I had already tried using the .toString() approach, but it doesn't at all solve the problem as pointed out by Daniel.

Comment: Yes. I also checked it after Daniel pointed it out. I heard about it from my colleagues and put it here. But did not properly test it for double digit numbers. In that case, the Array method might be the way out.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for the Array method. It appears that we can only use a Sequence or a List/Array as input to sc.parallelize() method and not just a singular value. But, I would also like to know that IF there is a way where we can use just one value to store into a RDD without having it to convert it into an Array.

Answer (score 4):

Basically the situation is that you have an `Int` and you want to write it to a file. Your first thought is to create a distributed collection across a cluster of machines, that only contains this `Int` and let those machines write the `Int` to a set of files in a distributed way.

I'd argue this is not the right approach. Do not use Spark for saving an `Int` into a file. Instead you can use a `PrintWriter`:

```
val out = new java.io.PrintWriter("filename.txt")
out.println(finalvalue)
out.close()
```

This will only work for writing to a local file. If you want to write to HDFS [it gets more complicated](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopDfsReadWriteExample).

Comment: I'm voting this answer up because I find it abusive creating an RDD to save a single value into a file.