# how to save a value in a file using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to **save a value in a file**, but keep getting an error

**I have tried**

```
.saveAsTextFile("/home/amel/timer")`
```

**REDUCER Function**

```scala
val startReduce = System.currentTimeMillis() 
val y = sc.textFile("/home/amel/10MB").filter(!_.contains("NULL")).filter(!_.contains("Null"))
val er = x.map(row => {
   val cols = row.split(",")
   (cols(1).split("-")(0) + "," + cols(2) + "," + cols(3), 1)
}).reduceByKey(_ + _).map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2)
er.collect.foreach(println)

val endReduce = System.currentTimeMillis()
val durationReduce = ((endReduce-startReduce)/1000).saveAsTextFile("home/amel/timer/")
```

**the error I'm receiving is on this line**

```scala
val durationReduce = ((endReduce-startReduce)/1000).saveAsTextFile("home/amel/timer/")
```

it says: `saveAsTextFile is not a member of Long`

The output I want is a number

Comment: The error is very clear, `endReduce-startReduce` gives you long and how could you use `saveAsTextFile` in `Long` . `saveAsTextFile` is a method in RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Long` does not have a method named `saveAsTextFile` If you want to write a Long value, there are many ways a simple way is to use java `PrintWriter`

```
val duration = ((endReduce-startReduce)/1000)
new PrintWriter("ome/amel/timer/time") { write(duation.toString); close }
```

If you still want to use spark RDD `saveAsTextFile` then you can use

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(duration)).saveAsTextFile("path")
```

But this does not make sense just to write a single value.

Comment: I am using Scala.

Answer (score 2):

`saveAsTextFile` is a method on the class `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#saveAsTextFile(java.lang.String)))

The expression `((endReduce-startReduce)/1000)` is of type `Long`, so it does not have this method, hence the error you are seeing "`saveAsTextFile is not a member of Long`"

This answer is applicable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32105659/8261

> Basically the situation is that you have an Int and you want to write it to a file. Your first thought is to create a distributed collection across a cluster of machines, that only contains this Int and let those machines write the Int to a set of files in a distributed way.
>
> I'd argue this is not the right approach. Do not use Spark for saving an Int into a file. Instead you can use a PrintWriter:
>
> ```
> val out = new java.io.PrintWriter("filename.txt")
> out.println(finalvalue)
> out.close()
> ```